# Does multidimensional array enumerator guarantee the same order for all implementations?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, specifications

Will this always print elements in the same order on all platforms?

```
foreach (var el in multidimArray) Console.WriteLine(el);
```

I'm looking for a quote from the specifications or anything official.

Comment: Suppose I wrote a class (*multidimArray*) that implements IEnumerable and returns content randomly.  So the answer is it depends...

Comment: @Eser your custom class will never be multidimensional array.

Comment: This question is not about **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** and asking for a specification quote is not the same as asking to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**.  In short there's no good reason to close this question unless you find a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the enumeration order of built-in arrays is well-defined and platform-independent.

See the relevant part of the [C# Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) (8.8.4 The foreach statement):

> The order in which foreach traverses the elements of an array, is as follows:
>
> - For single-dimensional arrays elements are traversed in increasing index order, starting with index 0 and ending with index Length – 1.
> - For multi-dimensional arrays, elements are traversed such that the indices of the rightmost dimension are increased first, then the next left dimension, and so on to the left.